# how i find last month same day sale and Last Month Present Week Sales?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

how i find last month same day sale and Last Month Present Week Sales? in sql

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: How do you define *last month same day*? E.g. today Aug 9 -> Jul 5 or Jul 9 or Jul 12? *Last Month Present Week*? 4 weeks ago or sometimes 5 weeks?

Comment: Can you provide a table definition? It could be: 
`CREATE TABLE sales ( sales_dt DATE NOT NULL,sales_amt NUMBER(15,2) );`, for example. Provide the table structure, and, ideally some sample data. The two interesting columns are the two I put into my sample table definition, and the query will run only on these two columns, ignoring the rest.

Comment: SELECT 'Week To Date Sales' PARTICULARS,
                   SUM (NVL (H.BILLAMT, 0)) TOTAL_INCULDING_OF_TAX,
                   COUNT (T.TRANHID) BILLS
                      FROM TRANH T, INVOICECASHSALES_H H
                     WHERE     T.TRANHID = H.TRANHID
                           AND T.DT <= (TO_DATE(:TODT))
                           AND T.DT >= TRUNC(TO_date(:TODT) , 'IW')
                           AND T.DOCSTATUSID IN (0, 1)  AND T.ISDOCNOASSIGN = 1  AND T.TRNTYPEID = 8 AND T.COMPANYID = :COMPANYID

Comment: as if this is a third week of i want previous moths same week from Monday to Sunday.